# Why does it take so long for notebooks to run on Databricks Workflows?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, pentaho

I am migrating an ETL implemented in Pentaho to Spark.

For this, I am using Databricks Workflows to orchestrate the Spark notebooks that are part of my new ETL.

The problem I have is that, when launching the job created in Databricks Workflows, the execution times are higher than in Pentaho and higher than expected.

[These graphics](https://i.postimg.cc/G34J7gMx/graph.png) show the comparison between Databricks and Pentaho execution times. As you can see, Databricks takes much longer than Pentaho. These tables correspond each one of them to a different notebook and they are executed as parallel tasks inside the job. Each notebook does several select statements from SQL tables, joins (lookups) and transformations, inserting the final results into a table.

I have tried running one of the notebooks in isolated form, outside the job I have created in Databricks Workflows. Concretely, I have tried with "TABLE 10" and it takes 4.04 minutes. I have added the following settings on the notebook and the execution time of "TABLE 10" decreases to 1.99 minutes.

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed", True)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize", 10000)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 32)
```

However, if I re-execute the job with these settings, "TABLE 10" takes 11.35 minutes.
These are the characteristics of the cluster in which I have launched the job:

- Databricks Runtime Version: Runtime: 9.1 LTS (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.1.2)
- Worker type: Standard_DS3_v2 (14 GB Memory, 4 Cores, Min worker 2, Max worker 4)
- Driver type: Standard_DS3_v2 (14 GB Memory, 4 Cores)
- Enable autoscaling: true

It is important to mention that in the "TABLE 10" notebook we read from 8 database tables, do multiple transformations, 3 joins and finally, write 128,497 rows to the database table. The code has not been optimized using cache(), repartitionByKey() or groupByKey().

I have tried changing the characteristics of the cluster to the following:

- Databricks Runtime Version: Runtime: 9.1 LTS (Scala 2.12, Spark 3.1.2)
- Worker type: Standard_DS4_v2 (28 GB Memory, 8 Cores, Min worker 1, Max worker 2)
- Driver type: Standard_DS4_v2 (28 GB Memory, 8 Cores)
- Enable autoscaling: true

These are the results of the execution times for "TABLE 10":

- Without any configuration and running the notebook in isolated form: 1.65 minutes
- With the configuration mentioned before and running the notebook in isolated form: 1.53 minutes
- Without any configuration and running the notebook in the job: 11.57 minutes
- With the configuration mentioned before and running the notebook in the job: 10.08 minutes

Why is there such a big difference on times when we execute tasks separately and parallelly? Should we configure spark settings on the cluster and not in the notebook? Is there any other way to optimize execution times?

**EDITED.**

[This image](https://i.postimg.cc/CLgWgchy/workflow-image.png) shows part of the job in Databricks workflow. Each task corresponds to a different notebook and these tasks are executed in parallel.

I have created the job using a JSON file. First, I create the task "Task 1", on which the rest of the tasks depend. Then, I create the tasks that are going to be executed in parallel (here I show the creation of the task "Table 3", it would be the same for the rest of the tasks). All the tasks are executed in the same cluster.

```
{
  "name": "ETL Spark",
  "max_concurrent_runs": 1,
  "tasks": [
    {
      "task_key": "task_1",
      "description": "Executing Task 1",
      "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": "task_1",
        "base_parameters": {
          ...
        }
      },
      "existing_cluster_id": "0315-122...",
      "timeout_seconds": 3600,
      "max_retries": 0,
      "retry_on_timeout": true
    }, 
    {
      "task_key": "table_3",
      "description": "TABLE_3",
      "notebook_task": {
        "notebook_path": "table_3",
        "base_parameters": {
          ...
        }
      },
      "depends_on": [
        {
          "task_key": "task_1"
        }
      ],
      "existing_cluster_id": "0315-122...",
      "timeout_seconds": 3600,
      "max_retries": 0,
      "retry_on_timeout": true
    }
    .
    .
    .                                                                                     
  ],
  "git_source": {
    "git_url": ...,
    "git_branch": ...,
    "git_provider": ...
  }
}
```

Comment: please edit post to include information about how workflows are configured... for example, do you have cluster reuse, etc.  I also recommend to reach a Databricks account team (if you have one) to review your approach.

Comment: @AlexOtt I have added some information about the configuration of the workflow